# Flutter error : A value of type 'OutletListModel' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<OutletListModel>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a error "A value of type 'OutletListModel' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List?'"

so how to resolve this error

```
List<OutletListModel>? selectedData;
```

[image]

Comment: So beautiful this screenshot.

Comment: can you include as code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the code line where the error appears with:

```
selectedData = [OutletListModel.fromJson(value.toJson())];
```

because `selectedData` expects an Array of `OutletListModel`;

Answer (score 0):

You can add item on list with `myList.add(YouItem)`. if you like to replace , you can do `myList = [.... ]`, but in this case `myList` shouldn't be final.

For your case, you can do

```dart
final newItem  = OutletModel.from(.....);
selectedData.add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OutletListModel.fromjson(value.tojson()).tolist()
```

make the response as list to assign